# Including LaTeX in pandoc preformatted section

Tags: latex, pandoc

I have a section of preformatted code in a pandoc document.  This is pseudocode, strictly speaking, and I'd like to include some rendered LaTeX within the preformatted section.  For example:

```
# Dijkstra's algorithm

Dijkstra's Algorithm (G,l)
Let S be the set of explored nodes
    For each u in S, we store a distance d(u)
Initially S = {s} and d(s) = 0
While S is not equal to V
    Select a node v not in S with at least one edge from S for which
        d'(v) = min_{e = (u,v) : u in S} d(u) + l_e is as small as possible
    Add v to S and define d(v) = d'(v)
EndWhile
```

I'd like, for instance, `d'(v) = min_{e = (u,v) : u in S} d(u) + l_e` to render as this would in the main text of the document: `$d'(v) = \mathrm{min}_{e = (u,v) : u \in S} d(u) + l_e$`

And no, entering it as `$d'(v) = \mathrm{min}_{e = (u,v) : u \in S} d(u) + l_e$` in the preformatted section doesn't do it...

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem. Have you found an interesting solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping characters like:

```
\$d'(v) = \mathrm{min}_{e = (u,v) : u \in S} d(u) + l_e\$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a latex question really... the package `fancyvrb` should do what you want. It lets you specify an escape sequence within a Verbatim block. E.g., after including \usepackage{fancyvrb} in the header:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}] \textit{% This is a comment}
First verbatim line.
\fbox{Second} verbatim line. \textcolor{red}{Third} verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}
```

Will render the word red on the third line in the colour red. Note \begin{Verbatim} with capital V distinguishes this from the regular verbatim environment.